# C# using statement inside #if DEBUG but not ship assembly

Tags: c#

I have a feature that I only want to happen on Debug, but do not want to ship the dll's that this feature requires. Is that possible to do?

I have:

```
#if DEBUG
using MyAssembly;
#endif
```

Of course MyAssembly is being referenced by the project. I would like MyAssembly.dll to not be shipped on a release mode. Can that be achieved? Will using Conditional("DEBUG") help in this regard?

Comment: `using` directives don't do anything in terms of assemblies - they're only about namespaces. You may want to make the assembly reference conditional in your project file... although if none of the code *refers* to code in the assembly in release mode, the C# compiler won't use the reference anyway, as far as I'm aware. (You should check though - and I'd conditionalize the reference anyway, to validate that.)

Comment: Thank you! Appreciate the feedback Jon!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

References that aren't required are usually removed automatically by the compiler, however: you can be more explicit by changing the csproj to include a `Condition` on the `PropertyGroup`. Something like:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
  <Reference Include="YourReference" />
</PropertyGroup>
```

(it could also be a `<PackageReference>` etc)

Comment: Marc, what do you mean when you say "references are usually removed" - if my code is under a #if DEBUG, then this code won't run in Release. But the assembly is still being deployed. I'm still trying your syntax .. getting some errors ..

Comment: @Bati  you'd need to check the IL, but the actual reference should be removed; however, you'd also need to check the deploy configuration, as you can deploy things that aren't references. Impossible to say much more without real files.

Comment: Adding the Condition to the reference node did the trick like so: 
<Reference Include="MyAssembly", Version=2017.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, processorArchitecture=MSIL" Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">

Answer (score 5):

It's perfectly fine to put a `using` directive in an `#if DEBUG` section, and it *will* remove that directive when compiled for debug.

However, that's only part of the story; it won't accomplish your objective by itself. The Solution Explorer in Visual Studio also has a **References** section. You would need to remove the reference for the assembly, as well, or it will still be included when you build.

I don't recall anything in the Visual Studio user interface that will let you do this, but I expect it should be possible somehow if you manually edit the Project file (it's just an MSBuild file). Personally, I try very hard to avoid doing things that require manual edits to the project files. Visual Studio wants to be able to own these files, and you can end up creating conflicts, where you and Visual Studio overwrite each other's changes.

Comment: Thank you for your input